# Check what server the application is running on?

Tags: php, linux, windows, unix

How can I check in a PHP script if it's running in a windows or Unix environment?

Answer (score 3):

check the variable PHP_OS

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'm using:

```
if(PHP_SHLIB_SUFFIX == 'so')// *nix (aka NOT windows)
{
    // Blah
}
else // Windows
{
    // Blah again
}
```

It's simple and you don't need to wade through the [massive number of options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738823/possible-values-for-phpos) of things like `PHP_OS`

Answer (score 1):

PHP_OS as mentioned above for a simple variable.

See also:  [php_uname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php)  For a longer answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (PHP_OS == 'WINNT')
{
   echo "Do windows stuff";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this information is available in the `$_SERVER` variable as follows:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']
```