# How to get Real IP from Visitor?

Tags: php, ip

I'm using this PHP code to get a visitor's IP address:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
```

But, I can't get the real IP address from visitors *when they are using a proxy*. Is there any way to get a visitor's IP address in this case?

Comment: You can only get the real ip from a proxy if that proxy is not fully anonymous otherwise all u will get is the proxy ip

Comment: You can see this link http://allinonescript.blogspot.in/2016/09/how-to-get-real-ip-isp-country-city-and-etc-from-visitor-using-php.html

Comment: Check this function: https://gist.github.com/RyadPasha/c025ddbc4a389d32917f05afde9001ea

Comment: Proxies like VPNs exist to hide the real IP address of the user. You are not able to get the real IP address of the current user if they are using them.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Try this php code.

```
<?PHP

function getUserIP()
{
    // Get real visitor IP behind CloudFlare network
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
              $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
              $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
    }
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}


$user_ip = getUserIP();

echo $user_ip; // Output IP address [Ex: 177.87.193.134]


?>
```

Comment: You should also handle the case where there are multiple proxies involved, why not?

Comment: This is bad as `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` can be forged. Only `REMOTE_ADDR` cannot.

Comment: @Pradeep Kumar Prabaharan, yes you do. If you run this code on a local server, you'll get your local ip, which is 127.0.0.1 or ::1

Comment: yes i got output on live server

Comment: What I do is : Adding all the IPs in an array in the order proposed here and I return this array. Like this, I can play with any available.

Comment: I just tested this while using putty to connect to a server creating a SSH tunnel and it did not find my real IP, only the servers IP

Comment: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can have multiple ip like '1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2' and this functions don't handle it. read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: This code is only for the situation that clients always request via trusted Proxy.

Comment: But what if ip is dynamic and change after each session?

Comment: Thanks a lot this fits as a best solution in case of cloudflair server. Superb solution

Comment: In my case this line `$client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];` prints an error, despite the `@`.

Answer (score 61):

This is the most common technique I've seen:

```
function getUserIP() {
    if( array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ) {
        if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], ',')>0) {
            $addr = explode(",",$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
            return trim($addr[0]);
        } else {
            return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
    }
    else {
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}
```

Note that it does not guarantee it you will get always the correct user IP because there are many ways to hide it.

Comment: Upvoted. This is one of the few solutions that properly handles the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header, which may contain a comma-separated list if the request passed through one or more proxies (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For#Format)

Comment: Since it's possible to spoof the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header, it's a good idea to test it with `filter_var(trim($addr), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)` to make sure you at least have a valid IP address before returning it.

Comment: Does this go in functions.php or wp-config.php?

Comment: @Garconis no one haven't mentioned WordPress here

Comment: Here's a PHP 7.x+ version of the above, including the `filter_var()` addition:

`function get_user_IP(): string {`

  `$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ?? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?? '';`

  `if (strpos($ip, ',') > 0) {`

    `$addr = explode(',', $ip);`

    `return filter_var(trim($addr[0]), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);`

  `}`

  `return $ip;`

`}`

[Sorry for the messed-up formatting — I can't post a block of code in here, apparently, just inline code.]

Also, if you're using PHP 8.x+ you can replace `strpos($ip, ',') > 0` with `str_contains($ip, ',')`

Answer (score 19):

This is my approach:

```
 function getRealUserIp(){
    switch(true){
      case (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])) : return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
      case (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) : return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
      case (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) : return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
      default : return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
 }
```

How to use:

```
$ip = getRealUserIp();
```

Comment: This is a very strange and confusing use of a switch statement. http://www.codethinked.com/dont-be-clever

Comment: What do you consider confusing exactly? For me, it is quite clear!

Comment: It's confusing because this is exactly what if/elseif is meant to be used for.

Comment: If you ever find yourself using switch(true), stop, and use an if statement(s).  How can this possibly be considered clearer than the accepted if/else?

Comment: I think the advantage (?) of a switch statement here is the way it's pre-processed in most languages to be run as a jump table and, in cases of large data or frequent use, can save on processing. However if it's not going to be run at a high frequency, clarity should not be sacrificed for processing speed.

Comment: I'd discourage this as an antipattern. Only constant cases can be reduced to a jump table. Otherwise, as here, every case is guaranteed to be tested until a break/return/etc is hit. So while this is more verbose and less readable than an elseif ladder, it's otherwise functionally identical.

Comment: For me: 
`code` private function getRealUserIp()
 {
  if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'])) { return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']; }
  if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) { return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']; }
  if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) { return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; }
  return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 }`code` is shorter and clearer

Answer (score 6):

Proxies may send a `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header but even that is optional.

Also keep in mind that visitors may share IP addresses; University networks, large companies and third-world/low-budget ISPs tend to share IPs over many users.

Comment: The header "specification" can handle multiple proxies, the chain of ips will be comma separated in the header value

Comment: Just one note. Third world ISP does opposite. They create dynamic ip for each login. So its multiple ips per user and not one ip for multiple user.

Answer (score 5):

This is my function.

benefits :

- Work if $_SERVER was not available.
- Filter private and/or reserved IPs;
- Process all forwarded IPs in X_FORWARDED_FOR
- Compatible with CloudFlare
- Can set a default if no valid IP found!
- Short & Simple !

---

```
/**
 * Get real user ip
 *
 * Usage sample:
 * GetRealUserIp();
 * GetRealUserIp('ERROR',FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE);
 * 
 * @param string $default default return value if no valid ip found
 * @param int    $filter_options filter options. default is FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE
 *
 * @return string real user ip
 */

function GetRealUserIp($default = NULL, $filter_options = 12582912) {
    $HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = isset($_SERVER)? $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]:getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    $HTTP_CLIENT_IP = isset($_SERVER)?$_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]:getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    $HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP = isset($_SERVER)?$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]:getenv('HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP');
    $REMOTE_ADDR = isset($_SERVER)?$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]:getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

    $all_ips = explode(",", "$HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR,$HTTP_CLIENT_IP,$HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP,$REMOTE_ADDR");
    foreach ($all_ips as $ip) {
        if ($ip = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, $filter_options))
            break;
    }
    return $ip?$ip:$default;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

apply this code for get the ipaddress:

```
    if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) { $pipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
 $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'); 
    echo "Your Proxy IP address is : ".$pipaddress. "(via $ipaddress)" ; } 
    else { $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'); echo "Your IP address is : $ipaddress"; }
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

If the Proxy is which you trust, you can try: (Assume the Proxy IP is `151.101.2.10`)

```
<?php

$trustProxyIPs = ['151.101.2.10'];

$clientIP  = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : NULL;

if (in_array($clientIP, $trustProxyIPs)) {

    $headers = ['HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

    foreach ($headers as $key => $header) {

        if (isset($_SERVER[$header]) && filter_var($_SERVER[$header], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {

            $clientIP = $_SERVER[$header];

            break;
        }
    }
}

echo $clientIP;
```

This will prevent forged forward header by direct requested clients, and get real IP via trusted Proxies.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` is how I see my ip when under a proxy on my nginx server.

But your best bet is to run `phpinfo()` on a page requested from under a proxy so you can look at all the availabe variables and see what is the one that carries your real ip.

Answer (score -6):

This works for Windows and Linux! It doesn't matter if it's localhost or online..

```
    function getIP() {
    $ip = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

    if (PHP_OS == 'WINNT'){
        $ip = getHostByName(getHostName());
    }

    if (PHP_OS == 'Linux'){
        $command="/sbin/ifconfig";
        exec($command, $output);
        // var_dump($output);
        $pattern = '/inet addr:?([^ ]+)/';

        $ip = array();
        foreach ($output as $key => $subject) {
            $result = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $subpattern);
            if ($result == 1) {
                if ($subpattern[1][0] != "127.0.0.1")
                $ip = $subpattern[1][0];
            }
        //var_dump($subpattern);
        }
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work every time because there are more OS than Win and Linux. Chek this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/738893/2127296

Comment: You're right, the solution just work for linux and win. :)

Comment: This returns the server's IP address. Not the visitor's. The question asked for the visitor's IP address.

Comment: Downvoted because this returns the SERVER's IP address, not the VISITOR's IP address.

Comment: Except the fact that as other said, it returns the server IP, while the question clearly is different, it uses `exec()` and is too complicated without a reason. Getting the visitor's IP does not require so much. Even if you use it to get the server IP, it should be 3 short lines of code to cover windows servers as well as linux.