# How to get the real IP address with PHP?

Tags: php, ip-address

I've tried other solutions posted her on slackoverflow like:

- [Get the client IP address using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php)
- [How to get Real IP from Visitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646690/how-to-get-real-ip-from-visitor)

But when I try the code I constantly get the 192.168... ip-address instead of 83.162.yyy.xxx (the one I get from: https://whatismyipaddress.com/)

Is there a way to get this ip address with PHP?

Comment: Are you testing this locally or on a remote server?

Comment: I'm testing this locally.

Comment: Then you will get, of course, your local ip and not the remote one ...

Comment: Ohh... sorry and thanks!