# How to track my outgoing links in codeigniter/php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've recently created a website using codeigniter so I can learn a php framework and I wonder how can I track the link that the people in my website is clicking to get out of my web.

Would be great to create a link like www.myweb.com/h1jkh13jk1h2 or some kind of unique string to that link and then store that in some statistics database.

Comment: Google analytics? Specifically the "behavior" section, pay attention to the bounces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use Google Analytics to get details of different aspects of your users behaviour on your site.

But if you only want to log requests for specific pages/methods on your site you could create a method to insert data into a database table every time any method gets requested:

```
private function _log_activity($page='default_page'){
   $user_ip = $this->getUserIP(); 
   $sql = "INSERT INTO log_table (user_ip, page, request_date)
       VALUES($user_ip, $page, NOW())";
   $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Copy the method getUserIP() in your controller from here: [How to get Real IP from Visitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646690/how-to-get-real-ip-from-visitor/13646735#13646735)

And usage in every method you want to track requests from:

```
$this->_log_activity('page_or_method_name');
```