# How to get ip address of the user pc in php

Tags: php

My web page offline return lpv4 format ip address

But uploading on server(online) it will show a lpv6 ip address.

**Main Purpose is to get client pc ip address on my website**

localhost wamp ip address

127. 0.0.somthing

Webhost ip address get is
2402:3a80:872:94a:d99f:d430:3dae:980

```
<?php
   echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Real IP from Visitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646690/how-to-get-real-ip-from-visitor)

Comment: Look at all the copied and pasted answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646690/how-to-get-real-ip-from-visitor Try googling the information you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the wamp are generate ipv4 formate ip address

And

Webserver are generate temporary ipv6 formate  ip address

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this :

```
   <?PHP

function getUserIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}


$user_ip = getUserIP();

echo $user_ip; // Output IP address [Ex: 177.87.193.134]


?>
```

Comment: it generat exact output is output is  2402:3a80:872:94a:d99f:d430:3dae:980

Comment: sir it will  exact same output no any change

Comment: sir own ip address search in google it display as like a  2402:3a80:872:94a:d99f:d430:3da form how can match 127.0.0.0.somthing please help us how convert one form for match condition

Comment: Not any change sir

Comment: @lalit What exactly u r getting ??

Comment: sir when get ip display is temporay ip address        permanant ipv4 get of client pc in php not get but ipv6 temporary address get in php online web site                                                                                                       ip type in google search it will depend your wifi network or own network sir i am try it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP version 5.3 or higher you can do like this

```
$host= gethostname();
$ip = gethostbyname($host);
```

This works when you are running a stand-alone script,not through the web server

Comment: Yes sir but it will generate the out put is  2402:3a80:872:94a:d99f:d430:3dae:980

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this on my page. hope it works.

```
 public function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}

echo get_client_ip();
```